# How to parse back string created using printfn "%A" in F#?

Tags: .net, parsing, f#

For an existing software, simple logging was achieved usign %A.
Not knowing this before, there is now need to work with this data again. (knowing this before, one would could use e.g. JSON from the start)

Is there an standard/idiomatic/elegant solution in F# for parsing that data back?
Luckily, it all follows the same structure, it is a list of records, where each record has two fields. Therefore the parsing function does not have to be generic if this makes things impossible.

```
type Image = ImageId of string
type Patch = PatchId of string
type ImagePatch = Image * Patch
type LogItem  = ImagePatch list

[(ImageId "267781.jpg", PatchId "3x4@11"); (ImageId "194292.jpg", PatchId "3x4@11")]
```

Comment: An example of the logged string that you want to parse would be helpful.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're writing a record with two fields. It looks like tuples. I agree with Scott, and in addition why not give us the print statement in the F# source.

Comment: If we pipe that last line into `|> List.iter (fun logItem -> printfn "%A" logItem)` then we get e.g. `(ImageId "267781.jpg", PatchId "3x4@11")` for one item. I would use grep to parse that. I would also maybe need to know what characters can occur in the unknown parts of the string, more specifically in the strings within the string. Assumptions can probably be made about what will not occur - e.g. `"` will not occur I guess - so that parsing can be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't necessarily a clean way to go back from calling `sprintf "%A" x` to the original object, because it's not really a serialization of the object, just a simple string representation.  If you want to go back and forth between strings and objects, you should use serialization and pick a standard format like JSON or YAML.  There are plenty of F#-compatible serialization libraries available that will do this for you automatically.

However, if you already have these strings and you just need to do your best to parse them back into objects now, you can try to rely on the standard behavior for built-in F# types when printed using the `"%A"` format, and make a decent attempt to re-create the original data.  Here's a partially implemented function that works for your example case.  There are TODOs in here for parsing record types, multi-field union cases, and arbitrary .NET objects.  However, since you're not using any of those in your example, this should work for you at the moment.

```
open System
open System.Reflection
open FSharp.Reflection

let tryParse<'t> (str: string) =
    let rec parseType (fsType: Type) (value: string) =
        match fsType with
        | union when union |> FSharpType.IsUnion ->
            printfn "Parsing Union %s (%s)" union.Name value
            let cases = union |> FSharpType.GetUnionCases
            match value.Split(' ') |> List.ofArray with
            | [] -> 
                None
            | [ caseName ] -> 
                cases 
                |> Array.tryFind (fun case -> case.Name = caseName)
                |> Option.map (fun case -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, [||]))
            | caseName :: args ->
                cases 
                |> Array.tryFind (fun case -> case.Name = caseName)
                |> Option.bind (fun case -> 
                    match case.GetFields() with
                    | [||] -> 
                        FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, [||]) |> Some
                    | [| field |] -> 
                        args |> String.concat " " |> parseType (field.PropertyType) |> Option.map (fun arg -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, [| arg |]))
                    | fields ->
                        // TODO: Implement multi-field unions
                        None)
        | record when record |> FSharpType.IsRecord ->
            // TODO: Implement record parsing
            printfn "Parsing Record %s (%s)" record.Name value
            None
        | tuple when tuple |> FSharpType.IsTuple ->
            printfn "Parsing Tuple %s (%s)" tuple.Name value
            let elements = FSharpType.GetTupleElements(tuple)
            let characters = value |> Seq.skip 1 |> Seq.take (value.Length - 2) |> Seq.toArray |> String
            match elements with
            | [||] -> 
                Some (box ())
            | [| element |] ->
                value |> parseType element
            | elements ->
                let args =
                    characters.Split(',')
                    |> Array.map (fun s -> s.Trim())
                    |> Array.mapi (fun i stringValue -> stringValue |> parseType elements.[i])
                    |> Array.toList
                    |> List.fold (fun acc cur -> acc |> Option.bind (fun a -> cur |> Option.map (fun c -> c :: a))) (Some [])                    
                args |> Option.map (fun arguments -> FSharpValue.MakeTuple(arguments |> List.rev |> List.toArray, tuple))
        | other ->
            printfn "Parsing Non-FSharp Type %s (%s)" other.Name value
            match Type.GetTypeCode(other) with
            | TypeCode.String -> 
                value |> box |> Some
            | TypeCode.Object ->
                // TODO: Implement non-F# Object parsing
                None
            | _ -> // handle primitives
                let parseFunction = other.GetMethod("Parse", BindingFlags.Static)
                if parseFunction |> isNull
                then None
                else parseFunction.Invoke(null, [|value|]) |> Some

    try 
        str |> parseType typeof<'t> |> Option.map unbox<'t>
    with ex -> 
        printfn "Error Parsing '%s' as %s: %A" str typeof<'t>.Name ex
        None
```

Then, if you use it for your example case, it should successfully parse the values:

```
type Image = ImageId of string
type Patch = PatchId of string
type ImagePatch = Image * Patch
type LogItem  = ImagePatch list

let log : LogItem = [(ImageId "267781.jpg", PatchId "3x4@11"); (ImageId "194292.jpg", PatchId "3x4@11")]

let stringValues = log |> List.map (sprintf "%A")

stringValues |> List.map tryParse<ImagePatch>
```

Gives you:

```
val it : ImagePatch option list =
  [Some (ImageId ""267781.jpg"", PatchId ""3x4@11"");
   Some (ImageId ""194292.jpg"", PatchId ""3x4@11"")]
```